# Multisite Drupal with Organic Groups problem.. custom /user and /user/register links for each group?

Tags: organic-groups

I am using Organic Groups for as a solution for Drupal Sub sites, it is working perfectly, even themes are switching via [Organic groups theme](https://drupal.org/project/og_theme) but I am having problem with `/user/register` and `/user` pages.

I want to pass context to user pages like `user/groupname/register` or `user/groupname` , so how can I do it ? because `/user` currently throws me out of the currently active theme for Organic Group.

Also one more thing, the Group Id which I want to pass should be as alias?like pathauto paths.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably look at [PURL](https://drupal.org/project/purl) for this, an API to make a part of a URL persistent.
PURL itself does nothing since it's an API, but you can get started with [OG Purl](https://drupal.org/project/og_purl).
Be warned, it's more advanced to be creating your own bridge like OG Purl does. A lot of motivation is required :)

Comment: thanks for your reply...Be warned, it's more advanced to be creating your own bridge like OG Purl does. A lot of motivation is required :)..can you please elaborate it? You mean to say that OG Purl is tough to consider? Also how about SPaces module?does it do the same?

Comment: I think Spaces is not maintained as much as OG. I would suggest anyhow to try OG Purl, it might do the trick for you with little config.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Can you please tell me from where can i use PURL..because its documentation says it is an API module..and doesnt seem to have any UI...i have now spent almost 3 hours even on google but to no avail...

Comment: /admin/config/search/purl provides you an interface. You need to programmatically create a Provider for ex based on your path. Next up you can programmatically create modifiers. A modifier is the fixed part in the URL, the ID is your choice to give a meaning to that fixed part. OG Purl gives examples on this.